# How is each critter unique in the critter.act array in Eloquent JavaScript Chapter 7?

Tags: javascript

I'm working through Eloquent JavaScript chapter 7 and I am trying to work out the part with the forEach within the `World.prototype.turn` function:

http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_elife.html#h_6OGIzAd5Tr

```
World.prototype.turn = function() {
  var acted = [];
  this.grid.forEach(function(critter, vector) {
    console.log(critter);
    if (critter.act && acted.indexOf(critter) == -1) {
      acted.push(critter);
      this.letAct(critter, vector);
    }
  }, this);
};
```

I understand what this is doing (I think), it is looping over each item in the Grid array and for every critter that is found (all critters have an act method within their prototype), it is checking the indexOf in the local array acted.
If it doesn't exist (-1), it is pushing it in.

My question is, how is each critter unique? When I `console.log(critter)` I get identical results: `{ direction: 'e', originChar: 'o' }`.

How does this not always return `-1` as the `indexOf()` after the first critter is pushed to the array?

Is it because within elementFromChar, every critter is created from the BouncingCritter constructor with `new`?

Thanks in advance, just trying to learn this thoroughly and try to understand it properly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript objects have an inherent uniqueness, so that

```
var x = { foo: 'bar' };
var y = { foo: 'bar' };
x !== y;

// But
var x = { foo: bar }
x === x;
```

It's a complex subject which you can read more about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness). In essence the indexOf is checking for that exact object, regardless of it's property values.